# How big is the studio in the Truman Show?

Tags: the-truman-show

> Coming to you now, from Seahaven Island, enclosed in the largest studio ever constructed and, along with the Great Wall of China<sup>†</sup>, one of only two man-made structures visible from space, now in its thirtieth great year, it's *The Truman Show*!
>
> <sub>Announcer, *The Truman Show*</sub>

It contains a small town, a sea, land beyond the town. But Truman almost reaches its edge during his first attempted escape.

**So how big is the studio?**

Is there any source that gives a size, or does it come down to measuring and estimating?

---

*<sup>† That the Great Wall of China is visible from space is [a common misconception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-made_structures_visible_from_space#The_Great_Wall_of_China), here repeated by the announcer in the movie.</sup>*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on the images seen in the film, the dome is approximately 8.5-10 miles wide at its base.

Unfortunately, due to a slight foreshortening effect in the satellite image, it's not really possible to be much more accurate than that.

[image]